# Automate System Lock

Tags: windows, powershell, bluetooth, automation

I am trying to write a Power Shell script which will check the connection status of paired Bluetooth devices in a certain interval (15 sec) and if found the device is out of range then will lock the users system. In the following code I am not able to figure out how to list all the paired device.

```
Do
{
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
$ListAllDevice = "Get the list of all paired Bluetooth Device"
$DeviceStatus = $ListAllDevice | Get-ItemProperty
$DeviceDetection = ($DeviceStatus).DeviceState
ForEach($IndDetection in $DeviceDetection)
{
If($IndDetection -eq 1)
{
Write-Host "device detected."
}
Else
{
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

}
}
}
While((Get-Date).hour -le 18)
```

While in other approach I also tried with the following code, but here Nodestatus doesn’t change enen if the connection out of range.

```
$ (Get-Device | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*Lenovo*'}).NodeStatus
```

Comment: Why don't you hire a developer?

Comment: If i I get some ideas then the scope of development comes. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a question that isn't off-topic?

Comment: is it possible to write a power shell script , which will check the status of paired Bluetooth device of my laptop and if my paired device goes out of connection range, then it will lock down my system. I found a similar one here https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/343515-powershell-script-proof-of-concept , but its locking system if any of the device is out of range . I want this to specify my device, which only will be monitored.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Hardly a useful answer. Not the answer's fault, though.

Comment: Could you please help me by providing some sample code or any link where such problem has been discussed?

Comment: Any luck llnsectable?

Comment: I don't gamble, so I don't understand, what *"luck"* has to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

First pair youre phone with youre pc then, there is a build in feature in windows 10 that can do this.

Please go to Settings -> Sign in Options -> Dynamic Lock

Comment: I am looking this to lock my system instantly. 1 minute window may prove costly for business.

Comment: For me it block the pc after 10 feet away.. they improved it really in the later builds

Comment: Is it possible to achieve over scripting ?